# indices are not showing in Kibana. How to make sure Elastic search is feeding logs to kibana

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, kibana, serilog

Steps I have done so far-

STEP 1, installed Elastic search 8.8.0.
Ran ElasticSearch.bat file and Got security token and password for elastic user.

Made following changes to elasticsearch.yml file

I. added action.auto_create_index: .monitoring*,.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history*,.ml*

II. disable xpack.security.enabled: false

III. xpack.security.enabled: false

IV. disable xpack.security.http.ssl:
enabled: false

V. xpack.security.transport.ssl:
enabled: false

STEP 2, installed Kibana. ran kibana.bat file

following changes in kibana.yml.

I. uncomment server.port: 5601

II.uncomment elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]

III. uncomment elasticsearch.username: "kibana_system"
elasticsearch.password: "E69PbxQAA4t9ctV2bwwwHJJ"

STEP:3 Accessed localhost:9200 and got the elasticsearch up and running

STEP 4: Accessed localhost;5601 and asked for elastic user and password, entered it and site is up and running

STEP 5:
Created a .net core webapi project

added log entry in weatherforcase controller

added following code in program.cs file ( Nuget package Serilog, Serilog.ASpnetCore, Serilog.Sinks.ElasticSearch)

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
   .Enrich.FromLogContext()
   .WriteTo.Console()
   .WriteTo.Debug()
   .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(
   new Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkOptions(
   new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
   {
       AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
       IndexFormat = "serilog-dev-022222"

   }).CreateLogger();
```

When Running the code , able to see logs in ElasticSearch.log file.

```
"updating index template [serilog-events-template] for index patterns [serilog-dev-022222]"
nothing shows up in Kibana.log file .
`
when accessing localhost:5601 , no indices shows. 

it seems like elastic search is not able to communicate with kibana. Never used security token generated by elasticSearch in Kibana. not sure where and how to use it. 

What am I missing ? any configuration setting I need to change so that both elastic search and kibana can communicate? Do I need to setup elastic search service ?

Have spent almost 2 days and getting frustrated now. Appreciate help.
```

Comment: It might be useful to enable [Serilog's debug mode](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics) to see if it's throwing any exceptions during log output.
`Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);`

Answer (score 0):

**Please note,** you might still face some issues because you have disabled quite a few security related properties. But for now try the following and let us know if you face any security related errors (e.g. could not generate token)

In your ***elasticsearch.yml*** file add the following -

```
xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true
```

Now in your terminal 'cd' into your elasticsearch folder and generate a token with kibana as scope -

```
./bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s kibana
```

This will write a token to the console itself. **NOTE:** Token is valid only for 30 mins. You can generate again if you're stuck and time passes by

Now, 'cd' into your kibana folder and add the token -

```
./bin/kibana-setup --enrollment-token <copied-enrollment-token>
```

Now head to your 'localhost:5601'. Go to 'Discover' and check for your logs.

***On a separate note,*** its much easier to setup the ELK Stack (Elasticsearch + Kibana) with docker. If you'd like to use this method, let us know and I'll add the docker related commands here.